# How to resolve error: return columns doesn't match expected columns?

Tags: postgresql

I write function in PostgreSQL. I am trying to fetch data from db by passing parameters in function .But i am getting error" ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type".
Here i created a function in which i am using union to get unique values.In first select stat. i amsetting value for account total that is used in below code.

**Function:**

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages ( p_nInstID numeric,p_nDeptID numeric)  
    RETURNS Table(
    res_ndept_id numeric,
    res_salaryPercent character varying,
    res_nclient_cpc_mapping_id numeric, 
    res_CPCCODE character varying, 
    res_sdept_name character varying, 
    res_sclient_dept_id character varying, 
    res_sAlternateJointUsePercentage character varying
    )
    AS  $$  
    declare v_AccountTotal numeric(18,2);
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select SUM(CAST (coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt, null) AS numeric(18,2))) as AccountTotal
            FROM Account acct
                INNER JOIN employeeaccountmapping eam 
                    ON eam.nacct_id = acct.naccount_id
                    AND acct.ninst_id =p_nInstID
              where acct.ndept_id =p_nDeptID ;

    SELECT  * 
    FROM 
        (select dep.ndept_id ,( CASE
                        WHEN v_AccountTotal =0 THEN 0
                        ELSE Round(SUM(CAST(coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt, null) AS numeric(18,2)) * cac.npercentage_assigned/100)  / v_AccountTotal *100,null)  
                        END     
                    ) as salaryPercent
        ,cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id,client.sclient_cpc AS CPCCODE,
        dep.sdept_name,dep.sclient_dept_id,'NO' ASsAlternateJointUsePercentage

        FROM account 
        INNER JOIN employeeaccountmapping eam 
        ON eam.nacct_id = account .naccount_id AND account .ninst_id=p_nInstID 
        INNER JOIN accountcpcmapping acm 
        ON acm.naccount_cpc_mapping_id = account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id 
        INNER JOIN cpcaccountcpcmapping as cac
        ON cac.naccount_cpc_mapping_id=acm.naccount_cpc_mapping_id
        INNER JOIN clientcostpoolcodes as client
        ON client.nclient_cpc_mapping_id=cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id
        INNER JOIN mastercostpoolcodes 
        ON mastercostpoolcodes .nmaster_cpc_id= client.nmaster_cpc_id
        INNER JOIN department as dep
        ON account.ndept_id=dep.ndept_id and dep.balternate_jointuse_percentage=FALSE
        where account.ndept_id =p_nDeptID 
        Group by dep.ndept_id,cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id,client.sclient_cpc
        ,dep.sdept_name,dep.sclient_dept_id, dep.balternate_jointuse_percentage
        UNION
        SELECT     Department_1.ndept_id, a_1.SumByCPC, clientcostpoolcodes.nclient_cpc_mapping_id, clientcostpoolcodes .sclient_cpc, Department_1.sdept_name, Department_1.sclient_dept_id , 'YES' AS sAlternateJointUsePercentage 

        FROM   department AS Department_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
               mastercostpoolcodes RIGHT OUTER JOIN
               clientcostpoolcodes RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                              (SELECT   JointUseStatistics_1.nccp_code, SUM(JointUseStatistics_1.npercent) /
                                                           (SELECT  SUM(jointusestatistics.npercent) AS SumByCPC
                                                           FROM          jointusestatistics INNER JOIN
                                                                                    roomdepartmentmapping ON jointusestatistics.nroom_allocation_id = roomdepartmentmapping .nroom_allocation_id
                                                             WHERE      (roomdepartmentmapping .ndept_id = Room_1.ndept_id)) * 100 AS SumByCPC, 
                                                          Room_1.ndept_id
                                  FROM jointusestatistics JointUseStatistics_1 INNER JOIN roomdepartmentmapping  AS Room_1 ON JointUseStatistics_1.nroom_allocation_id = Room_1.nroom_allocation_id
  GROUP BY JointUseStatistics_1.nccp_code, JointUseStatistics_1.npercent, Room_1.ndept_id) AS a_1 ON 
          clientcostpoolcodes .nclient_cpc_mapping_id = a_1.nccp_code ON mastercostpoolcodes .nmaster_cpc_id = clientcostpoolcodes .nmaster_cpc_id ON 
          Department_1.ndept_id = a_1.ndept_id                      
        WHERE     (Department_1.balternate_jointuse_percentage = 'TRUE')
                AND (Department_1.ninst_id= p_nInstID)
    )AS My 

    where (ndept_id= p_nDeptID )
    ORDER BY My.sdept_name,My.CPCCODE ;
    END;    
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can have executable code after a `RETURN QUERY`, it works similar to `RETURN NEXT`.   If you can't figure out how to combine these two queries to get the structure of the table you're trying to return you could create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` and insert into that, then return the results from that. You could also try a CTE using `WITH` to build complex queries piecewise

Comment: In my code i used union .need to create two temporary tables for that two select statement?

Comment: You have used `UNION` only in the **second** statement, but you still have two distinct statements where only the first one is used for `RETURN QUERY`. If you want to return the result of **both** statements you need to combine all of them using a union. Looking at the code, it seems the **first** statement should store its result in `v_AccountTotal` (and should not be prefixed with `return query`) and the **second** query then should be the one returning the table (using the variable `v_AccountTotal`)

Comment: do you mean i need to return query after first statement?

Comment: When i used RETURN QUERY after first statement then it gives error like query has no destination for result data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you want is the first query to just retrieve the count, store that in your variable, then use that variable in the second query which is the actual source of the result of the function.

So the first query should **not** use `return query` but `select .. into ..` store put the result into the variable.

Then you can prefix the *second* query with `return query` to return its result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetDeptListForViewModifyJointUsePercentages ( p_nInstID numeric,p_nDeptID numeric)  
    RETURNS Table(
    res_ndept_id numeric,
    res_salaryPercent character varying,
    res_nclient_cpc_mapping_id numeric, 
    res_CPCCODE character varying, 
    res_sdept_name character varying, 
    res_sclient_dept_id character varying, 
    res_sAlternateJointUsePercentage character varying
    )
AS  $$  
declare 
  v_AccountTotal numeric(18,2);
BEGIN
    -- no RETURN query here!!
    select SUM(CAST (coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt, null) AS numeric(18,2))) 
      into v_accounttotal  --<<< store result in variable
    FROM Account acct
        INNER JOIN employeeaccountmapping eam 
            ON eam.nacct_id = acct.naccount_id
            AND acct.ninst_id =p_nInstID
    where acct.ndept_id = p_nDeptID;

    -- this is the query that should be returned
    RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM (
      select dep.ndept_id,
             CASE WHEN v_AccountTotal = 0 THEN 0
                  ELSE Round(SUM(CAST(coalesce(eam.npayroll_amt, null) AS numeric(18,2)) * cac.npercentage_assigned/100)  / v_AccountTotal *100,null)  
             END as salaryPercent,
             cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id,
             client.sclient_cpc AS CPCCODE,
             dep.sdept_name,
             dep.sclient_dept_id,
             'NO' AS sAlternateJointUsePercentage
      FROM account 
        INNER JOIN employeeaccountmapping eam 
        ON eam.nacct_id = account .naccount_id AND account .ninst_id=p_nInstID 
        INNER JOIN accountcpcmapping acm 
        ON acm.naccount_cpc_mapping_id = account.naccount_cpc_mapping_id 
        INNER JOIN cpcaccountcpcmapping as cac
        ON cac.naccount_cpc_mapping_id=acm.naccount_cpc_mapping_id
        INNER JOIN clientcostpoolcodes as client
        ON client.nclient_cpc_mapping_id=cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id
        INNER JOIN mastercostpoolcodes 
        ON mastercostpoolcodes .nmaster_cpc_id= client.nmaster_cpc_id
        INNER JOIN department as dep
        ON account.ndept_id=dep.ndept_id and dep.balternate_jointuse_percentage=FALSE
        where account.ndept_id =p_nDeptID 
        Group by dep.ndept_id,cac.nclient_cpc_mapping_id,client.sclient_cpc
        ,dep.sdept_name,dep.sclient_dept_id, dep.balternate_jointuse_percentage
        UNION
        SELECT Department_1.ndept_id, a_1.SumByCPC, clientcostpoolcodes.nclient_cpc_mapping_id, 
               clientcostpoolcodes .sclient_cpc, Department_1.sdept_name, Department_1.sclient_dept_id, 
               'YES' AS sAlternateJointUsePercentage 
        FROM   department AS Department_1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN mastercostpoolcodes  --<<< missing join condition !!
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN clientcostpoolcodes --<<< missing join condition !!
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
              SELECT   JointUseStatistics_1.nccp_code, 
                       SUM(JointUseStatistics_1.npercent) /
                                                        (SELECT  SUM(jointusestatistics.npercent) AS SumByCPC
                                                         FROM jointusestatistics 
                                                           INNER JOIN roomdepartmentmapping ON jointusestatistics.nroom_allocation_id = roomdepartmentmapping .nroom_allocation_id
                                                         WHERE (roomdepartmentmapping .ndept_id = Room_1.ndept_id)) * 100 AS SumByCPC, 
                       Room_1.ndept_id
              FROM jointusestatistics JointUseStatistics_1 
                  INNER JOIN roomdepartmentmapping  AS Room_1 ON JointUseStatistics_1.nroom_allocation_id = Room_1.nroom_allocation_id
              GROUP BY JointUseStatistics_1.nccp_code, JointUseStatistics_1.npercent, Room_1.ndept_id
          ) AS a_1 ON clientcostpoolcodes.nclient_cpc_mapping_id = a_1.nccp_code 
                   ON mastercostpoolcodes.nmaster_cpc_id = clientcostpoolcodes.nmaster_cpc_id  --<< that should be somewhere else
                   ON  Department_1.ndept_id = a_1.ndept_id     --<< ??????
        WHERE (Department_1.balternate_jointuse_percentage = 'TRUE')
          AND (Department_1.ninst_id= p_nInstID)
    ) AS My 
    where (ndept_id= p_nDeptID )
    ORDER BY My.sdept_name,My.CPCCODE;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that there are several syntax errors in your second query because the join conditions are scattered around the query. I have tried to highlight them.

Comment: return query after first statement gives error  query has no destination for result data.

Comment: then you didn't copy the `into v_accounttotal` part from my answer

Comment: Thank you for your guidance i am getting result.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql, function returns a single value. But in your example, you are trying to return multiple outputs in terms of number of rows and columns.

You can alternatively use a `stored procedure` and save the output in a `temporary table`. Later use that table for your use.

Comment: This is wrong. Functions declared as `returns table()` can return more than one row (with more than one column)